# find a no. in an array of nxn containing all distinct elements in O(n)

Tags: algorithm

Give an nxn array of elements such that each row is in ascending order and each column is in ascending order, devise an O(n) algorithm to determine if a given element x in the array. You may assume all elements in the nxn array are distinct.

Please tell me if somebody knows the solution to this problem.

Comment: Could you give us an example - what it should and should not do? I can't really understand your writing.

Comment: 3 4 5
6 7 8
9 10 11

now if somebody ask me to search for 9 then it should return true else false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start at 1st row last column i.e. i=0, j = n-1

```
while true {
if (j< 0 || i > (n-1) )
 break; // element not found
if (array[i][j] == x)
 return i,j
else if (x < array[i][j])
 j = j -1; // and repeat
else 
 i = i+1; // and repeat
}
```

This is O(n). Explanation:

Start at first row and last column. i=0;j=n-1 Everytime x is less than currElement decrement j else increment i.

Comment: I din't understand, please explain me the method you are following. What is the value of j and i in the starting?

Comment: i=0,j=n-1 i.e. the first row and the last column